# Error when storing input in variable in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

> So in this code I am storing my input in var and when I want to print this var with the button you can't see the output in the console. But when I print it like `print(input.get())` it works perfectly

```
 def button(text="Hello", width=20, height=20, x=20, y=200, bg="white", 
      command=0, font="Verdana 10 bold"):
      button = Button(frame, text=text, width=width, height=height,font=font, 
      command=command, bg=bg)
      button.place(x=x, y=y)



 def printer():
     print(var)
   
input = Entry(width=50)
input.place(x=20, y=220)
var = input.get()



button("Submit", 6, 2, 20, 240, command=printer)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: why are you using  ```input```,a built-in method, as a variable name

Comment: The command "button" seems to me quite strange. In general is `(master, text = 'About', command=self.about, width = 20).grid(row = 0, column = 1)`. But please, insert the full code.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `.get()` method on initialisation, so `var` holds an empty string since there is nothing in the input field.

Now, when you call `print(input.get())` then the current value is fetched and printed, hence it works and the former doesn't.